# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_markdown2'

Tags: python, django

I'm currently doing Harvard Course about Web Programming. I need to convert my html page on website to markdown, so I installed into my conda virtual environment markdown2 and I added it to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. But I have a problem when I try to runserver or migrate I am getting an error ModuleNotFoundError. I tried to create another virtual environment but that doesn't work as well.
Thank you for your tips in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\petrk\anaconda3\envs\henv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\petrk\anaconda3\envs\henv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\petrk\anaconda3\envs\henv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\petrk\anaconda3\envs\henv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\petrk\anaconda3\envs\henv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\petrk\anaconda3\envs\henv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_markdown2'
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'encyclopedia',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_markdown2',
```

]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error. I tried switching over to a venv, and using django-markdown2, but both of these workarounds didn't solve the error.
Finally, I found that since I had installed the markdown2 module using `pip3 install markdown2`, I also had to "runserver" using `python3`.

TLDR:
Previously, I was running `python manage.py runserver` throughout the CS50 tutorial, but after using the markdown2 module installed with pip3 I had to use the command `python3 manage.py runserver` for everything to work smoothly again.

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I had to install to my virtual enviroment pip install django-markdown2 instead of just markdown2.